# Python programming

Tags: python

My assignment ask to make a function call readFasta that  accepts  one  argument: the  name  of  a  fasta  format  file (fn)  containing  one  or  more  sequences. The  function  should  read   the  file  and  return  a  dictionary  where  the  keys  are  the  fasta  headers  and  the  values   are  the  corresponding  sequences  from  file  fn  converted  to  strings.  Make  sure  that   you  don’t  include  any  new  lines  or  other  white space  characters  in  the  sequences  in  the  dictionary.

For ex, if afile.fa looks like:

```
>one
atctac
>two
gggaccttgg
>three
gacattac
```

then the a.readFasta(f) returns:

```
[‘one’ : ‘atctac’,
‘two’ : ‘gggaccttgg’,
‘three’: ‘gacattac’]
```

If have tried to write some codes but as I am totally newbie in programming, it didnt work out very much for me. Can everyone please help me. Thank you so much. Here are my codes:

```
import gzip

def readFasta(fn):
    if fn.endswith('.gz'):
        fh = gzip.gzipfile(fn)
    else:
        fh = open(fn,'r')

    d = {}

    while 1:
        line = fh.readline()

        if not line:
            fh.close()
            break

        vals = line.rstrip().split('\t')
        number = vals[0]
        sequence = vals[1]

        if d.has_key(number):
            lst = d[number]

            if gene not in lst:
                # this test may not be necessary
                lst.append(sequence)
        else:
            d[number] = [sequence]

    return d
```

Here is what I got in my afile.txt

> one atctac
>
> two gggaccttgg
>
> three gacattac

Comment: You would probably have much better luck at http://biostar.stackexchange.com It's better geared for bioinformatics type questions

Comment: You should re-format your code. highlight your code and press the icon with numbers.

Comment: I'm trying to edit the formatting and it shows correctly in the preview, but my changes only affect the `import gzip` line. i wash my hands at the risk of community wiki'ing it.

Comment: I am trying to fix but I dont know how to so I just enter for everyline T.T hope everyone can understand it....my bad

Comment: Strange. I tried to format it and everything shows up fine on the preview pane. On saving, everything looks screwed up.

Comment: @pmt0512: Python, and I think even moreso StackOverflow really dislikes mixes of spaces and tabs. In general it is easiest to force your editor to forget tabs exist (at least for Python source). http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonEditors

Comment: reformatted code with only spaces. Thanks @msw

Comment: looks nice now, thanks so much :)

Comment: @Manoj: I hope that isn't a new/separate bug from the one [I reported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63390), but it looks so since my bug only affects rollbacks.

Comment: Two homeworks in a row?  Don't you have a professor, other students to talk to, maybe a textbook to read?  Asking the Internet isn't the solution to everything.

Comment: Also, don't mark questions as "wiki".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your post is slightly confusing. I assume that you want it to return a dict. in that case, you would write it as `{'one': 'actg', 'two': 'aaccttgg' }`. if you correctly presented the file format, then this function should do the trick.

```
import gzip

def read_fasta(filename):
    with gzip.open(filename) as f:
        return dict(line.split() for line in f)
```

Comment: I just used the code but still got error with python 2.6 version:

Comment: >>> import readFasta as b
>>> b.readFasta('afile.txt')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "readFasta.py", line 37, in readFasta
    
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @pmt0512. if you put it in a file by itself, that would help. I don't know what line the code I gave you starts at in that file. It should be in a file nine lines long for reference.  As it stands though, there's no place in my code (AKAIK) that could yield an index error.

Comment: one atctac
two gggaccttgg
three gacattac

Comment: AH, I dont know how to edit the file in comment to make it look exactly, but it contain 3 lines, first line will be one, tab, atctac, the 2nd line will be two, tab, ggaccttgg, and 3rd line is three, tab, gacattac. I just looking to make the function returns when it read this file as the dict that the assignment give as example. Thanks

Comment: @pmt0512. you should edit your post then because that's a totally different format then what you have displayed right now.

Comment: @pmt0512. I just noticed that you uploaded the file. I updated my solution. Are you sure that it's in a zip file and not just a text file?

Comment: it actually just the text file, I am not use much about the gzip command line, I just put it there as someone told me that just fine to put it there, so I dont know, should I take if off? Thanks AaronMcSmooth